# Responding to AJAX request from a Java Socket

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, sockets, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to have a simple java server respond to an XmlHttpRequest, but I am not sure how. As of now, the socket on the server gets the request of the browser. After getting the sockets output stream, the server writes to it, then closes all connections. Is there something more to this? I assume that you would need a header to respond to the request correctly, if so what would that header be. Thanks!

Here is what I am doing right now. I can't seem to get the browser to accept the message, however.

Edit:
The Java server code:

```
private String HEADER = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n" +
"Cache-Control: private\n" +
"Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n" +
"Expires: Sun, 21 Feb 2100 20:39:08 GMT\n" +
"Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5\n" +
"Date: Sun, 21 Apr 2012 20:39:07 GMT\n" +
"Connection: close\n" +
"Content-Length: 10\n";

         browserWriter =
                new PrintWriter(
                        browser.getOutputStream(),true);

            while((data = browserReader.readLine()) != null) {
                if (data.indexOf("POST") != -1) {

                    /* TODO TEST - TAKE OUT */
                    browserWriter.println(HEADER + "APPLESAUSE");
                    browserWriter.close();
                    browserReader.close();
                    browser.close();
                    return;
```

Javascript:

```
  xmlhttp.open("POST","http://10.0.2.15:1024/password?url=" + site, false);
  xmlhttp.send(null);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All XmlHTTPRequest's require an HTTP response, so HTTP headers are needed. It's ok to close the connection once the response is given. This is basically just acting as a web server.

Some HTTP header fields: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

See here for the official spec: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

A decent tutorial here: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/http-headers-for-dummies/

Answer (score 1):

For the browser to understand the server's response, it should be valid according to the `Response` format specified in the [HTTP Protocol](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html). The only thing that's required in addition to the actual response body is a status line, typically `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` if the request succeeded.

Additional [HTTP Headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14) such as `Content-Length` or `Content-Type` can help the browser process the response more efficiently, but if you start setting lots of these you're basically implementing your own HTTP server and I'd recommend using [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) or something else off the shelf before going down this route.